# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Error (Android Development)

Tags: java, android

I have a method called hash button however on press the application crashes. Any idea why this is happening?

I have included parts of my logcat below, any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks, Mark

```
02-12 16:59:26.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 16:59:26.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2416): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
```

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
02-12 16:59:26.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2416):     at com.example.braintraining.MediumGame.Hash(MediumGame.java:102)` Fix that line

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`. Arrays are 0 base indexed in Java. The indexes starts from 0 to array.length-1.

Comment: @ZouZou Is there any way that I can fix the error?

Comment: @user3301631 Without showing your code, that will be hard to tell.

Comment: @ZouZou Any chance I can possibly email you my code?

Comment: @user3301631 Post it here, in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access an element with index equal to size of the array. If you're looping, use

```
for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
   //Your code
}
```

Comment: int x = 4;//2 + (int)(Math.random()*((6-2))+1);
  if(x > 2) {
   
   for(int y = 2; y<x; y++){   //Code  }}

Comment: I haven't initialised an array or using another one in this project so far.